# Microsoft Shims Can't Debug Method Under Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

I have a test method that is fine when I run it but fails with an exception when debugged.
Here is the tested method and output from VS Test Runner below. The exception is coming from ShimsContext.Create()

Info: VS 2012 Permium Update2
[image]

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestResolveDateWithShim()
    {
        using (ShimsContext.Create())
        {
            // arrange
            DateTime someTestTime = new DateTime(2013, 1, 14);

            Fakes.ShimDateHelper.PreviousOrCurrentQuarterEndDateTime =
                time => someTestTime;

            var appCache = new Fakes.StubIAppCache();
            var series = new StubISeries();
            series.KeyGet = () => SeriesKey.MyKey;

            // act
            Report report = new Report(SeriesKey.MyKey, appCache);
            DateTime resolvedDate = report.ResolveDate(series, DateTime.Now);

            // assert
            Assert.AreEqual(someTestTime, someTestTime);
        }
```

Comment: I solved it. It was resharper that was causing the problems. In the resharper tab under options. Under Tools->Unit Testing -> MSTest I unchecked the 'Use Legacy Runner' checkbox. Now it worksd and I can still use resharper to help me test. I I jsut disable all test options in resharper it works as well but I want some options from resharper because they are very helpful.

Comment: Whenever you solve your issue, please post it as an answer so that other users may benefit from your solution.

Answer (score 6):

I solved it. It was resharper that was causing the problems. In the resharper tab under options. Under Tools->Unit Testing -> MSTest I unchecked the 'Use Legacy Runner' checkbox. Now it worksd and I can still use resharper to help me test. I I jsut disable all test options in resharper it works as well but I want some options from resharper because they are very helpful.

Comment: Just a side note - I'm using Resharper 7 which has the same MS Test option, but is now labelled `Run tests with MSTest.exe (not recommended)`. I don't know exactly which R# version had this text changed, but just in case people are unable to use your answer, I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Thanks for solving this. And hey, don't be shy, go ahead and accept your own answer.